# Google Spreadsheet: Use cell referencing in "Change Color Based on Rules"

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In "Change Color Based on Rules", one can specify the text color to be any color as long as certain rules are followed:

[image]

My question is, instead of hard-coding the values, can I use cell reference? In the example above, instead of hard-coding the values to be a "Yes", can I set it as something like  `$B$3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seven years is a *very* long time in the life of Google Sheets (so far) and amongst many changes various oft requested enhancements to conditional formatting have been made. One can now use a cell reference in the way requested by OP. The appearance is quite different however:

[image: WA6976 example]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, Spreadsheet does not support formulas in the change color based on rules yet.  (often requested though!)